# Rmarkdown/Shiny works but does not save .md .html output

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, knitr, r-markdown

I am trying to make an interactive Rmarkdocument with shiny elements, and upload this file to a server running Shiny Server. To get this to work, I need output from (local) Rstudio that I can upload (I think I need the  .md and .html files).

For illustration, here is a sample script:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r, echo=FALSE}
inputPanel(
  selectInput("n_breaks", label = "Number of bins:",
              choices = c(10, 20, 35, 50), selected = 20),

  sliderInput("bw_adjust", label = "Bandwidth adjustment:",
              min = 0.2, max = 2, value = 1, step = 0.2)
)

renderPlot({
    hist(faithful$eruptions, probability = TRUE, 
    breaks = as.numeric(input$n_breaks),
    xlab = "Duration (minutes)", main = "Geyser eruption duration")

  dens <- density(faithful$eruptions, adjust = input$bw_adjust)
  lines(dens, col = "blue")
})
```
````

When I hit Ctrl+Shift+K to Knit this, I get output that an .md and an .html file have been written (to /tmp/RtmpazfnvB/.knit.md and to  /tmp/RtmpazfnvB/file65ab7ab54e0d.html, respectively). Also, a working interactive document pops up. So far so good:
[image: Rmarkdown Shiny Output]

The problem is when I try to save the output files.

- If I click 'Open in Browser', I an empty tab opens in my browser
- If I redirect my browser to /tmp/RtmpazfnvB/file65ab7ab54e0d.html, I get a working html, but this is without the interactive elements
- The /tmp/RtmpazfnvB/.knit.md does not seem to exist

Additional info:

- Running Rstudio with `sudo` didn't change anything,
- Setting the permissions to /tmp to 777 didn't change anything
- I am running Ubuntu 17.10, R version 3.4.0, have run update.packages(ask = FALSE)
- adding `html_document: keep_md: true` still does not generate an md file
- The code below gives the error "could not find function "inputPanel":

  ```
  rmarkdown::render(input = "markdown_shiny_test1.Rmd", clean=F, runtime = "shiny", output_dir="~")
  ```

Does anyone know what the problem for .html/.md creation could be here? Many thanks!